# Passing Scoped RegionManager to a different Region

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, prism

In a WPF Project using PRISM I have two Regions. A `ContentRegion` and a `ToolBarRegion`.

When creating a new SubShell in `ContentRegion` a `Scoped RegionManager` will be created.

Content Region:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static common:RegionNames.ContentRegion}" />
```

ToolBar Region:

```
 <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static common:RegionNames.ToolBarRegion}" />
```

So very basic until here.
My Problem is when I want to navigate from the Toolbar into the SubShells with the `Scoped RegionManager` the Regions don't exist.

**So how can I pass the `Scoped RegionManager` from the SubShells in the ContentRegion to my View in the ToolBarRegion?**

Comment: I would like to know further about your App design as I don't completely understand why are you trying to use Scoped Regions. Both Content and ToolBar Regions are defined separately in the Shell View? Or is the ToolBar Region defined in the SubShell View? If the scenario refers to the first case, the regions would not exist in the Scoped RegionManager because they are defined out of the SubShell bounds. More information about [Scoped RegionManager here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec43).

Comment: Thanks for your reply GOstrowsky! I Use Scoped Regions because I navigate the `SubShell` multiple times into the `ContentRegion` and each Subshell has its own Regions. But for each Subshell I want to navigate a ToolBarView into the `ToolBarRegion` having the same `RegionManager` like the corresponding `SubShellView`. 
Maybe if this sounds to complicated I will try to draw this scenario.

Comment: Based on my understanding, each SubShell defines a new Content and ToolBar Regions. And you would like to Navigate/Activate a ToolBarView on the SubShell's ToolBar region. Would this be correct? If regions defined in the Shell and SubShell Views have the same names, it may be causing names conflict, and it would not register the SubShell regions. Please try different names.